# Keyboard plugins not working with Android Crosswalk builds?

Tags: cordova, crosswalk-runtime

I've tried the Cordova SoftKeyboard plugin : http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.plugin.softkeyboard

As well as the PhonoStar SoftKeyboard plugin : https://github.com/phonostar/PhoneGap-SoftKeyboard

Both work when I do traditional builds with Cordova 3.4 and Eclipse. But, when I build using Cordova-Crosswalk (both 5.34.104.5 and 6.35.131) neither plugin seems to work. There is no error output in LogCat. I have a console.log() in the javascript that makes sure the libraries are there, and they seem to be.

All of my other installed plugins seem to work: Google Analytics, KeepScreenOn, Cordova Device and Cordova Dialogs.

Any suggestions? Is there a particular plugin structure that works with Crosswalk?

Answer (score 0):

there is a compatible issue that Crosswalk based CordovaWebView could not popup while calling API showSoftInput(), I have reported a bug for Crosswalk https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-1814 , I think it will be fix soon.

Comment: This bug was closed and not fixed.

Comment: The workaround in that link didn't work for me, either.  This seems to be an outstanding issue